# In ReactNative Keyboard pushing the contents away, unexpected behaviour KeyBoardAvoidingView

Tags: javascript, android

Iam trying to implement small a input form in react-native. But when I try opening the keyboard, it pushes and wraps the content away. I tried using KeyBoardAvoidingView and ScrollView at different views but not worked for me(did not get desired output).[Here is the output after opening the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jszC1.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve] that shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml file generated by React Native and add the following attribute in the concerned screen/activity.

```
<activity
     ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"> 
</activity>
```

or

```
  <activity
         ...
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  </activity>
```

Comment: Sorry that I have not mentioned that Iam using expo project. AndroidManifest.xml is not available in expo project. Do you have any idea for expo projet.